# Do we know why Goose was not in Endgame?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame, captain-marvel

It felt at some points like *Avengers: Endgame* brought back practically everybody who's ever been relevant in the MCU.  (Slight exaggeration, but not a very big one.)  So I can't help but wonder, where was Goose in all of this?  Because seriously, can anyone deny that it would have been incredibly awesome to see

> some of Thanos's goons get flerken'd

in the final battle?  And while one may reasonably point out that you can't expect an adult cat from the 1990s to still be alive in 2023, remember that

> Goose is not a cat, but an alien creature that may well have a much longer lifespan.  (Has this ever been established?)

Has anyone from Marvel said anything on the subject of Goose's absence from *Endgame*?

Comment: I was busy, sorry about that

Answer (score 7):

The interview with the screenwriters at the NYT https://www.nytimes.com/2019/04/29/movies/avengers-endgame-questions-and-answers.html (sorry if paywalled) states that everything they shot with Captain Marvel happened before Captain Marvel (the movie) was *written* so they didn't have a lot of flexibility with adjusting based on that later movie.